# confusing related to member hiding

Tags: java, inheritance, member-hiding

if static method of child class is hidden by static method of parent class having the same signature, then why is my output as follows:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Obcount.num_obj();
        Doing.num_obj();
        
    }
}


class Obcount{
    static int count;
    Obcount(){
        count++;
    }
    static void num_obj() {
        
        System.out.println("i am parent class");
    }
    
}

class Doing extends Obcount{
     double i;
     double j;
     Doing(double i,double j){
         this.i = i;
         this.j = j; 
     }
     void prod() {
         System.out.print(i*j);
     }
     static void num_obj() {
         System.out.print("i am child class");
     }
    
     void div() {
            System.out.println(i/j);
        }
}
```

The output is:

i am parent class
i am child class

shdnt the second line of output be " i am parent class" as well? pls clarify

Comment: "static method of child class is hidden by static method of parent class ". It is the other way around. "if a subclass defines a static method with the same signature as a static method in the super class, in such a case, the method in the subclass hides the one in the superclass."  [Reference](https://www.javatpoint.com/method-hiding-in-java)

Comment: Java will always select the more specific method which in the case of static methods with the same signature is the one declared in the most specific (i.e. child) class. So if you have a hierarchy like `C extends B extends A` and `A` and `B` declare the same static method `m()`, then `C.m()` will resolve to `B.m()` while `B.m()` and `A.m()` won't need any further resolution. TLDR: the child class method "hides" the parent class method.

Comment: @asinkxcoswt says right, its a concept of method hiding. and static members attached with the class only and after overriding each class have their own implementation.